# LWC Lookup Filter using another field on record

Tags: lightning-web-components, lookup-filter

I have custom objects: events, registration and rooms. 
A registration has a lookup for the event and a lookup for the room.
The room have an event lookup as well.

In lightning web components I want the lookup to find only rooms that belong to the same event as the registration.

I would like to use the lookup filter of the assigned room field but willing to learn something new.

I have added the filter for the assigned room lookup field in custom object registrations but it does not bring up any results in LWC or in the Layout. 
[image]

Without the filter I get results showing recent rooms.

NOTE: After deleting and re-adding the filter several times it seems to work. I will check more soon because that does not make sense.

Comment: Slightly confused - are you trying to write an LWC to handle this or are you talking about a standard Lookup field in a layout used in a Lightning Record Page?

Comment: @PhilW Trying to make standard filter work in LWC and in a layout. the filter does not work in either

Comment: So this is nothing to do with lightning web components, right? Just a lookup filter against a field in a layout, yes? If I have misunderstood, you probably need to [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/291530/edit) your question to add the detail that I and other folks in the community need in order to understand it. Some screenshots of what you've tried etc. would also be handy. Check out [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips around asking a good and clear question - this will raise the chances of getting an answer!